# App returns to home screen, when add is displayed using TimerTask()

Tags: android, timertask

It's my first app to create , I new to android ,

I am designing an app that displays the Advertisement Screen, every 1 minutes when user opens the  app ,

The Advertisement Screen works perfectly as expected ,but the problem is when the Advertisement Screen get exit , the app gets returned to the home screen no matter where the user was currently in the Activity Screen

The app flow

SplashScreen.java -->  AdSplash --> DiamondWorldMenus (  Home screen )

DiamondWorldMenus .java

```
public class DiamondWorldMenus extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {


on Create(.......){

    public void startAdSplashForEvery1Minutes(){
            //starting AdSplashTimer.java every 5 minutes
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();

            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {      

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent viewTargetActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AdSplash.class);
                            startActivity(viewTargetActivity);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },60000, 60000);
        }
  }

}
```

AdSplash.java

```
public class AdSplash extends Activity 
{
    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 8000;
    WebView ad;
    WebSettings web_settings;
    WebViewClient yourWebClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ad_splash);
        String url = "http://some_add_link.aspx";
        yourWebClient = new WebViewClient();
        ad=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.ad_web);
        ad.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
        ad.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);       
        ad.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
        ad.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
        ad.loadUrl(url);







              Thread splashTread = new Thread() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) 
                    {
                        sleep(100);
                        if(_active) 
                            waited += 100;
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) 
                {}
                finally 
                {
                    finish();
                    Intent in1 = new Intent(AdSplash.this,DiamondWorldMenus.class);
                    startActivity(in1);
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: From what you have said it seems there is only one SplashScreen other than the HomeScreen apart from the AdSplash. SO obviously it should go to the HomeScreen right?

Comment: AdSplash.class put code for this class.

Comment: No there are many other Screen , when user is in any of these and AddScreen appears , then the app returns to the DiamondWorldMenus ( Home screen )

Comment: Comment finish(); line in your AdSplash

Comment: @RIT ---- doesn't worked

Comment: Removed finally{} block

Comment: the problem is , at initial the flow is SplashScreen.java --> AdSplash --> DiamondWorldMenus .... then, the TimerTask() starts , its checks for 5 minutes and shows addscreen ... ,,,.If I remove finally{} , the flow would be disturbed...